# .NET: How to check the type within a generic typed class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

How do I get the type of a generic typed class within the class?

An example:

I build a generic typed collection implementing *ICollection< T>*. Within I have methods like

```
    public void Add(T item){
        ...
    }

    public void Add(IEnumerable<T> enumItems){
        ...
    }
```

How can I ask within the method for the given type *T*?

The reason for my question is: If *object* is used as *T* the collection uses Add(object item) instead of Add(IEnumerable<object> enumItems) even if the parameter is IEnumerable. So in the first case it would add the whole enumerable collection as one object instead of multiple objects of the enumerable collection.

So i need something like

```
if (T is object) {
    // Check for IEnumerable
}
```

but of course that cannot work in C#. Suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Michael

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Personally, I would side step the issue by renaming the `IEnumerable<T>` method to `AddRange`. This avoids such issues, and is consistent with existing APIs such as [`List<T>.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx).

It also keeps things clean when the `T` you want to add implements `IEnumerable<T>` (rare,  I'll admit).

Answer (score 32):

You can use: `typeof(T)`

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(object) ) {
    // Check for IEnumerable
}
```

Comment: This answers the question asked in the title.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the `is` operator in a generic class/method you have to limit `T` to a reference type:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T theItem) where T : class
{
    if (theItem is IEnumerable) { DoStuff(); }
}
```

Comment: I think he's just concerned when an non-generic IEnumerable is passed as a System.Object when T is System.Object